# Background Images around flexible Content?

Tags: html, css

im trying to get some background images around a content div. Thing is, the content div should have a flexible width (no problem). The background pics should always be left and right attached to the content div. BUT: the horizontal scrollbar should only be triggered, when the user reduces the window to the width of the content div.

Picture: [Structure](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bbedc8b3f4.gif)

I came up with something like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="header">/div>
 <div class="wrapper">  
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right"></div>
     <div class="content">Content</div>
 </div>
    <div class="footer">/div>
</div>



.wrapper{
 margin:auto;
 width:950px;
position:relative;
}

.left {
background:transparent url(../images/left.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-120px;
width:120px;
height:500px;
}

.right {
background:transparent url(../images/right.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:-120px;
width:120px;
height:500px; 
}
```

Scrollbars always appear when window hits the right absolute div. I need them to be two divs (left/right) because the content div should be flexible and not hide the background when it extends to much.

Someone got a tecnique for this?

Comment: you want the scrollbar to ignore the presence of the absolutely positioned elements, and only react to the content div dimensions?

Comment: Thats right. i already solved it with ilhan negis answer. but maybe you got a different approach...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an unnamed plain root container div.

Add this style for that div (or give a class/id name to wire css deceleration). 
Main point is `min-width`... Keep it same with your container div's width.

also adding `body,html{margin:0;padding:0;}` will be nicer.

```
style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;min-width:950px;position:relative; height:100px;"
```

this will work fine exept for ie6. 
For ie, you can apply some js magic.

Let's assume you're using jquery library and you gave id name "shell" to your root container div. 
Then try this script only for ie6.  (create exclusion or something like that):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#shell').each(function(){
  var that = this;
  var contentWidth = 950;
  check();
  $(window).resize(check);
  function check() {
   var winWidth = Math.ceil($('body').width());
   if(winWidth <= contentWidth) {
    $(that).css({'width':contentWidth});
   } else {
    $(that).css({'width':'100%'});
   }
  }
 });
});
```

This script will make "shell"s width 100%. (if  browser's width is larger than 950px) otherwise  it'll lock shell's width with 950px and that will enable scrollbar.

Comment: Thats it. I just removed the height attribute. Didnt knew min-width and overflow trigger the scrollbar like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for a website, the solution I came with was this:

I created an image with the left and right content on the background and the space of the content in the middle to just be a solid color, even though the image is 1400 x 539 it weights 12 KB, so it's pretty good.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
  </body>
</html>


body {
  background: #fff url(left-and-right.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not my problem. using only one background image does not allow flexible width AND having the background always look the same. The more widht you have the less background you will see, right?
Thats what i want to solve with two background images, always attached to the left and right of the content.

Comment: d'oh! I forgot about the flexible width. I don't see this happening without the use of Javascript.